# Run Function Every 5 Minutes

Tags: php, html, mysql, websocket

I have one socket connection based PHP file. Its continues running. This file have one function like below

```
$dataRemove = removeNumbers();
$numberRemove = $dataRemove["data"];
$errorRemove = $dataRemove["error"];
for($i = 0; $i < count($numbers); $i++) {
    $w->sendPresenceUnsubscription($numbers[$i]);
    $w->pollMessage();
}
```

I want run this function automatically every 5 minutes, can anyone please suggest me how I can do it?
Thanks

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/2368/how-do-i-set-up-a-cron-job

Comment: Yeah, I'd go with cron instead of having php run forever on a loop.

Comment: @IncredibleHat I do not want re execute full php file. Instead I just want re execute function only. Thanks

Comment: @cale_b I do not want re execute full php file. Instead I just want re execute function only. Thanks

Comment: I dont actually see a function just some inline code

Comment: @PritiPatel - no need to add the same comment multiple times :) we can all see them.  You can execute a single function with a cron job, send some arguments to the PHP file that is called, for example....

Comment: @IncredibleHat I have need login for run that function and if I run it via chrome, it will login again and it will stop my other files which is running 24/7. Thanks

Comment: Maybe you need javascript and ajax on a loop.

Comment: @IncredibleHat basically I have not found solution for this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51078056/making-simple-event-listener-in-php , so I am thinking for implement temporary solution like this. Thanks

Comment: @cale_b let me know if You can help me for this issue (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51078056/making-simple-event-listener-in-php) I need even paid service for it. Thanks

Comment: ReactPHP, amphp, basic event loop bindings... tons of options for pure php solution. But, you don't want to use simple tools such as cron.. only a fool wastes time where no time should be wasted.

Answer (score -2):

You can use the code below for you code and call the function again and again after regular interval.

```
set_time_limit(0); 
while(true) {
    callYourFunction();
    sleep(500);
}
```

Refer for set_time_limit() function http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php#refsect1-function.set-time-limit-notes

NOTE: not recommended but still can use it to fix your issue.

Comment: Yeah, this almost never works in real life.  Timeout problems and other problems always interfere.

Comment: Just suggested, else cron can help with the implementation.

Comment: @ArchitGoyal there is not improving it. Best approach would probably be a crontab entry for this.  The way you have it, your process will hang forever, best it not happen under an http SAPI call.

Answer (score -2):

```
set_time_limit(0);
while(true) {
    function();
    sleep(500);
}

function function() {
    $dataRemove = removeNumbers();
    $numberRemove = $dataRemove["data"];
    $errorRemove = $dataRemove["error"];
    for($i = 0; $i < count($numbers); $i++) {
    $w->sendPresenceUnsubscription($numbers[$i]);
    $w->pollMessage();
    }
}
```

Just simply use `set_time-limit(0);` to make it run forever, and the `sleep(500);` to make it wait 5 minuts.